# WordPress database error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I keep getting the following error when trying to update a listing in WordPress:

```
[warn]  mod_fcgid: stderr: WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
right syntax to use near '' at line 1 for query 
 SELECT listing_child_name 
 FROM wp_fsrep_listings 
 WHERE listing_id =  made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/curberry/page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), call_user_func_array, fsrep_content, include('/plugins/fs-real-estate-plugin/themes/default/listing_details.php'), fsrep_pro_listing_child
```

A user can create a listing, but cannot go back and update the listing. The error above shows the error.

The error is followed by:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  
array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given 
in /home/curberry/public_html/wp-content/plugins/fs-real-estate-plugin/common_functions.php on line 1185
```

Comment: Looks like someone is circumventing the WP DB object and hasn't built the query right to properly escape input.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/

by the way,I found you use real estage plugin on error.
Don't not use it brother.

Please check 
http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/118310/WordPress-FS-Real-Estate-SQL-Injection.html